# How to unlock 24 hours locked content from a website?

Tags: javascript, html

Hey I am enrolled in a course and that course is using a platform named podia. Now what that platform do is it helps to run a 5 day workshop which means you can unlock each and every module day by day. Now i was thinking is it possible to change the script of the website and unlock all the content. I inspected a script and saw this code.

```
  Podia.Customer = {"id":2581507,"email":"(removing my email )xxx@gmail.com","first_name":"dhruv","last_name":null,"created_at":1587913778521};
```

Now i was thinking maybe i can change the created at value in order to bypass the locked content. But i don't know in which format this is. Its just a random number or is it something logical in Javascript. Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

Hi usually that value is in milliseconds.
In fact if I assume that value is in ms `1587913778521` and covert to time then get that date: `Sun Apr 26 2020 15:09:38 (UTC format)`

1. [conver ms to time](https://currentmillis.com/)
2. [other link](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php)